# MEAN Stack failed to instantiate module app

Tags: html, angularjs, rest, web, mean-stack

I am trying to create a tagging tool where a user can manually tag untagged call centre requests by means of a web page application.

The app structure is as follows:

```
client
    js
        controllers
            editTagController.js
            editUntagController.js
            tagnamesController.js
            tagsController.js
            untagsController.js
        imports
            jquery-3.1.1.js
        app.js    
    views
        index.html
        edit-tags.html
        view-tagnames.html
        view-tags.html
        view-untags.html    
node_modules
    body-parser
    express
    jquery
    mongoose
    tether
server
    controllers
        tagscontroller.js
    models
        tag.js
        name.js
package.json
README.MD
server.js
```

My error message is at the below. I am currently running it locally and I can't seem to fix it at all. I think it has something to do with my order of imports in my index.html file.

I think it could also be something to do with the factory that I am defining named **taggingApp**. However I am not sure if it is just this latter error or another error with it. Any help/advice on conventions would be helpful.

```
Failed to instantiate module taggingApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
    at https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:40:222
    at q (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:39:488
    at q (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:21:179
```

Here is my code:

server.js

```
var express           = require('express'),
    app               = express(),
    bodyParser        = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose          = require('mongoose'),
    tagsController = require('./server/controllers/tagscontroller');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/STDBank');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));

//  app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
//    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
//  });

//REST API
app.get('/api/tags', tagsController.list);
app.post('/api/tags/:id', tagsController.update);
app.get('/api/untags', tagsController.listUntags);
app.post('/api/untags/:id', tagsController.updateUntags);
app.get('/api/tagnames', tagsController.listName);

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m Listening...');
})
```

tagscontroller.js **(Server Side)**

```
var Tag = require('../models/tag');
var TagName = require('../models/name');

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Tag.find({}, function (err, results) {
    console.log("RESULTS ARE: ",results);
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<results.length;i++){
        if(results[i].itag[0]){
            arr.push({
            _id : results[i]._id,
            name : results[i].name,
            itag : results[i].itag
            });
            console.log("enter if: ",  results[i]);
        }//end of if statement
        else{
            console.log("enter if: ",  results[i].itag);
            console.log("enters else statement ",  arr);

        }//end of else statement 
    }//end of for loop 
    console.log("results ",arr);
    res.json(arr);
  });
}

module.exports.update = function(req, res){
    var arr = [];
    //for(var k = 0;k<req.body.intentTag.length();k++){
    //  arr[k]= req.body.intentTag[k];
    //}
    console.log("Server side entered ", req.body.itag);
    Tag.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: {
            name: req.body.name,
            itag: req.body.itag //arr
            }
        },  function (err, tag){
            if(err) res.send(err);
            res.json(tag);
    });
}

module.exports.listUntags = function (req, res) {
  Tag.find({}, function (err, results) {

    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<results.length;i++){
        if(results[i].itag[0]){
            //console.log("enter if: ",  results[i].intentTag);
        }//end of if statement
        else{
            //console.log("enter if: ",  results[i].intentTag);
            //console.log("enters else statement ",  arr);
            arr.push({
            _id : results[i]._id,
            name : results[i].name
            });
        }//end of else statement 
    }//end of for loop 
    //console.log("results ",arr);
    res.json(arr);
  });
}

module.exports.updateUntags = function(req, res){
    var arr = [];
    //for(var k = 0;k<req.body.intentTag.length();k++){
    //  arr[k]= req.body.intentTag[k];
    //}
    console.log("Server side entered ", req.body.itag);
    Tag.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: {
            name: req.body.name,
            itag: req.body.itag //arr
            }
        },  function (err, tag){
            if(err) res.send(err);
            res.json(tag);
    });
}

module.exports.listName = function(req, res){
    TagName.find({}, function(err, results){
        console.log("RESULTS: ", results);
        res.json(results);

    });
}
```

If we are only assuming a call to /tags then you will need to know what the Tag model looks like:

tag.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var TagSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    itag: []// arr
}, {collection : "requests"});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("taggingApp", ["ngRoute","ngResource"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/tags", {
      templateUrl: "../views/view-tags.html",
      controller: "tagsController"
    })
    .when("/tags/:index", {
      templateUrl: "../views/edit-tags.html",
      controller: "/controllers/editTagController"
    })
    .when("/untags", {
      templateUrl: "../views/view-untags.html",
      controller: "/controllers/untagsController"
    })
    .when("/untags/:index", {
      templateUrl: "/views/edit-tags.html",
      controller: "/controllers/editUntagController"
    })
    .when("/tagnames", {
      templateUrl: "../views/view-tagnames.html",
      controller: "/controllers/tagnamesController"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/tags"
    });
});
```

Due to our previous assumption we can see that we need the tagsController and the view/view-tags.html files

view-tags.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Tag Details" data-ng-model="search" />
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Request</th>
      <th>Tag Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter: search" data-ng-click="editItem($index)">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.tag}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
  <button data-ng-click="untaggedView()" class="btn btn-primary">Untagged View</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button data-ng-click="tagnamesView()" class="btn btn-primary">View Tagnames</button>
</div>
```

tagsController.js **(Client Side)**

```
app.controller("tagsController", ["$scope", "$resource", "$location", "$routeParams", function($scope, $resource, $location, $routeParams) {

  var Tag = $resource("/api/tags");
  Tag.query(function(results){
     $scope.items = results; 
     console.log("The items = ", items);
  });

  $scope.untaggedView = function() {
    $location.path("/untags");
  };

  $scope.editItem = function(index) {
    $location.path("/tags/" + index);
  };

  $scope.tagnamesView = function() {
    $location.path("/tagnames");
  };

}]);
```

And then Lastly index.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <!--   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="tether@*" data-semver="1.3.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.1/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1>  Tagging Tool</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div data-ng-view=""></div>
          <p>{{search}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagsController.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/untagsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editTagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editUntagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagnamesController.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any Help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

I have added the comments in below however it seems that it cannot get that Angular. Any ideas on that?

**NEW view-tags.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="taggingApp">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <!--   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->  
    <!-- <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script> -->
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="tether@*" data-semver="1.3.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.1/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1>  Tagging Tool</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div ng-view=""></div>
          <p>{{search}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagsController.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/untagsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editTagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editUntagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagnamesController.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[These are the errors I have been getting when I updated my HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3pIG.png)

**EDIT:**
Here is your error Aravind:

[@Aravind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkhZc.png)

**NEWEST EDIT:**

edited index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="taggingApp">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="//www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <!--   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->  
    <!-- <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script> -->
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="tether@*" data-semver="1.3.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.1/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1>  Tagging Tool</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div ng-view=""></div>
          <p>{{search}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagsController.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/untagsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editTagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/editUntagController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/tagnamesController.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am still receiving the [$injector:modulerr] error however the others are all sorted out.

**EDIT:**

I have changed the relative directories of my App.js so that they actually load the controllers and views. On top of that I have added an app definition into every controller. This fixes my current errors, gives me no other errors however the data is not displaying

Comment: Hi! Didn't you miss importing angular.js before angular-route?  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Include angular scripts in the index.html and your reference for the ngResource is missing

Use

//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.9/angular-resource.js

Update :

Replace this line

```
"cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.9/angular-resource.js"
```

with this

```
"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.9/angular-resource.js"
```

**Reason : you missed //**

1. if // is not there it will be searching in your localhost.
2. adding // will be searching in the internet http or https is not mentioned because // refers to your current protocol and makes request correspondingly

Comment: I have edited my HTML file as you said however the injector error is still persisting, thus I changed it to a hyrbid of the comment in the initial post. AS well as just his version to try. However the error is still there

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the one error but not the other one. Check edits for error and changes and let me know if you have any idea how to resolve it. Thank you